# Problems with CRON job and php script

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a php script that fetches a RSS feed and parses the feed and produces a secondary feed.  When I run the script on the command line, it runs just fine:

```
sudo /usr/bin/php -f myscript.php > outputfile.xml &
```

In my crontab is have:

```
*/30 * * * * nice /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/myscript.php > /path/to/outputfile.xml &
```

The output file when run from the command line passes rss validation per, http://validator.w3.org, But when I run the script as a CRON job it does not run to completion.  It stops in the middle and produces an incomplete RSS feed.

Basic Algorithm of script

fetch rss feed

parse rss feed with simplePie.

foreach feed item

open the link element

grab an img tag address

finish creating the feed.

During the CRON execution the script fails on the open link element in the for each loop.  This is using the simple_html_dom object in PHP to get the image tag from the rss item article.

Don't understand why it does not work using CRON.

Comment: Means fetch rss feed downloading it to a file?

Comment: When your job runs from the command line, it runs as the user who executes the command.  When the job runs from /etc/crontab, it runs as root unless you su to a different user.  Are the jobs running as different users?  If so, I would look at permissions.

Comment: If my hunch about users is right, this link will help - http://superuser.com/questions/170866/how-to-run-a-cron-job-as-a-specific-user

Comment: In both examples I have run the script using the root user.  I used sudo from the command line and then crontab uses the root user.  I will update the post.

Comment: I was able to use another user's crontab and the script ran fine.  I have other scripts like this in the root crontab.  Just don't understand why this one works as one user and not the root user.

Comment: Okay.  Didn't try that.  but I did fix the problem.  SimplePie uses a cache directory.  I noticed the cache directory existed where the script was but not in root's home directory.  When I added that directory to root's home directory.  The script worked.  Weird since other scripts are using the same library, SimplePie, and are working just fine.